# How to make breadcrumb of specific part of URL

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I have to generate breadcrumbs for each page of website, where as the url is bit complex.

This is my URL

> http://1.1.1.1/Company/?route=enterprise/projects/manage&id=52rw9649ffwerwd3d9018154&section=newpanel

Now I have to get "enterprise/projects/manage" from the url after the "route=" and generate breadcrumbs of each route.

Below is the PHP code that I am using, which only creates breadcrumb like this "Home>>Company " whereas I need breadcrumb like this "enterprise>>projects>>manage".

```
 // This function will take $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and build a breadcrumb based on the user's current path

    function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
        // This gets the REQUEST_URI (/path/to/file.php), splits the string (using '/') into an array, and then filters out any empty values
        $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));

        // This will build our "base URL" ... Also accounts for HTTPS :)
        $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

        // Initialize a temporary array with our breadcrumbs. (starting with our home page, which I'm assuming will be the base URL)
        $breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");

        // Find out the index for the last value in our path array
        $last = end(array_keys($path));

        // Build the rest of the breadcrumbs
        foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
            // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
            $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));

            // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
            if ($x != $last)
                $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";
            // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
            else
                $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
        }

        // Build our temporary array (pieces of bread) into one big string :)

        return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
        //return parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    } 
    ?> `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want the route parameter, then you need to mine that out of the url.

Here is a function to extract only the route parameter.

```
function getRouteParamAsArray($url) {
    // Get the query part of the url. i.e. after the ?
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    // echo "query = $query\n";
    // explode it into parts a=1, b=2 etc
    $parts = explode('&', $query);

    // echo print_r($parts, true) . "\n";

    // Now covert the parts into key value pairs
    // by taking each item and exploding on '='
    $arr = [];
    array_walk($parts, function($item) use (&$arr)
    {
        // echo "$item\n";
        $a = explode('=', $item, 2); // convert into key/value
        $key = $a[0];
        $value = $a[1] ?? null; // just in case
        $arr[$key] = $value;
    });
    // Now we have key value pairs
    //echo print_r($arr, true) . "\n";
    // See if there is a 'route' key
    if ( array_key_exists('route', $arr) ) {
        $routeParts = explode('/', $arr['route']);
    } else {
        $routeParts = [];
    }
    // echo print_r($routeParts, true) . "\n";
    // echo 'breadcrumb: ' . implode(' > ', $routeParts) . "\n";
    return $routeParts;
}
```

Integrate it into your function:

```
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
    // This gets the REQUEST_URI (/path/to/file.php), splits the string (using '/') into an array, and then filters out any empty values
    $path = getRouteParamAsArray($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    // This will build our "base URL" ... Also accounts for HTTPS :)
    $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

    // Initialize a temporary array with our breadcrumbs. (starting with our home page, which I'm assuming will be the base URL)
    $breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"{$base}Company/">$home</a>");

    // Find out the index for the last value in our path array
    $last = end(array_keys($path));

    // Build the rest of the breadcrumbs
    $crumbPath = '';
    foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
        // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));
        if ( ! empty($crumbPath) ) {
            $crumbPath .= '/';
        }
        $crumbPath .= $crumb;
        // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
        if ($x != $last)
            $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"{$base}Company/?route={$crumbPath}\">$title</a>";
        // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
        else
            $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
    }

    // Build our temporary array (pieces of bread) into one big string :)

    return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
    //return parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply @ryantxr, it does work, I do get this breadcrumb **enterprise>>projects>>manage** but now if i click on projects , instead of taking me to  **http://1.1.1.1/Company/?route=enterprise/projects** , it takes me to **http://1.1.1.1/projects**.

Comment: Seems like your original code should be concatenating the route crumbs as they are created.

Comment: I think it is this part of the code

`if ($x != $last)
            $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";
        // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
        else
            $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
    }` 

@ryantxr

Comment: Can you please have a look at my code, I am really stuck at this problem. @ryantxr

Comment: Just change the string generated. I updated the code. You should check it and confirm that it works.

Comment: thanks for the help, I added "\Company\" in the string now it works fine, but there is one last issue and this is in my breadcrumb **home>>enterprise>>projects>>manage** , enterprise is a folder , so if a click on this, page doesn't show any thing, how would I handle this. Thanku soo much for the help. It means a lot.

Comment: Add an index.php in the enterprise folder.